# @TestPropertySource not initialising boolean property

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am trying to override one of my declared variables by using @TestPropertySource. Below is my code for the test :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"calculator.enabled=true"})
public class CalculatorTest {

    private Calculator calculator;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        calculator = new Calculator();
    }

    @Test
    public void isEnabled_Success_Test() {
        Assert.assertFalse(calculator.isEnabled());
    }
}
```

Here is the class to be tested :

```
@Component
public class Calculator {

    @Value("${calculator.enabled:true}")
    private boolean isEnabled;

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }
}
```

However, I always end up with the test actually passing when it should not since the isEnabled field gets initialized with the default value of false.
What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Where is your spring/test config? Sounds like `Calculator` is not a "bean", then `@Value` is "worthless" (does nothing, `boolean` default/unassigned value is `false`)

Comment: You are doing `new Calculator` which renders `@Value` useless. Inject the `Calculator` so you get a spring managed instance.

Comment: @xerx593 - `Calculator` is a bean. I forgot to add the `@Component` annotation to the posted question.

Answer (score 0):

As M. Deinum already said you are creating the Calculator with "new Calculator();" in the init() method. Therefore it is not a spring-managed bean.

You should have spring create the calculator.
Pre-condition "spring-boot-starter-test" E.g.:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"calculator.enabled=true"})
@SpringBootTest(classes = Calculator.class)
public class CalculatorTest {

    @Autowired
    private Calculator calculator;
    
    @Test
    public void isEnabled_Success_Test() {
        Assert.assertTrue(calculator.isEnabled());
    }
}
```

Moreover, you are currently using JUnit4 maybe it is a good idea to move to JUnit5